# Tensorboard fails to plot model weights for all epochs during training

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to plot the progression of my model's weights during training using `add_scalar`, however, the tensorboard plot only shows the weights for any one epoch.

What I mean by this is, when I load tensorboard, I only see "epoch 0" in the scalars section even if I have run my model for 10 epochs. However, I dont have this issue while plotting histograms in the same code.

My code is as follows:

```
for epoch in total_epochs:
          train model
          calculate error
          optimizer.step()
          calculate average loss
          
          for name,weight in model.named_parameters():
              SummaryWriter.add_histogram(name, weight, epoch)
              SummaryWriter.add_scalar(str(name), weight, epoch)
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a screenshot of your tensorboard interface, please?

Comment: @Ivan here is an example of what I was talking about: https://imgur.com/a/l2ZL5da

I ran the training for 10 epochs but only epoch 0 and 1 are visible on this scalar plot but the histogram has all 10

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible standalone code to expedite the trouble shooting process? Thanks!